# Recover/Restore Window 8.1 modern app

Tags: windows-8.1, powershell

guy I trying restore window 8.1 modern app
Windows Store Apps Troubleshooter had run.
But when run *Reinstall and Re-Register All Windows Apps for All Accounts* using **Powershell** face this problem
[image]

Comment: You sure that command is even suppose to work on Windows 8.1.  In any event, if your machine does not have that particular .xml file, you will have to mount a Windows 8.1 ISO and the file contained within it instead.

Comment: Yes, work in win 8.1. Other way exclude re-format it. My family remove all appxpackage, i try reset leave control panel and winstore